# Show that $4\leq |z+3|+|z^2-z+4|\leq 11$ where $|z|=2$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, maxima-minima

Let $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and$|z|=2$.Show that $$4\leq |z+3|+|z^2-z+4|\leq 11$$
Is there a non-calculus way to do this

**My Attempt:**

I used method which involved calculus.

Let $z=2(\cos t+i\sin t)$

$\Rightarrow|z+3|=\sqrt{13+12\cos t}$

$\Rightarrow|z^2-z+4|=2|4\cos t-1|$

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{13+12x}+2|4x-1|$ where $x\in [-1,1]$

Now here $f(-1)=f(1)=11$

$f'(x)=\frac{6}{\sqrt{13+12x}}-8<0$ for $x\in [-1,\frac{1}{4})$

and $f'(x)=\frac{6}{\sqrt{13+12x}}+8>0$ for $x\in (\frac{1}{4},1]$

So, clearly $x=\frac{1}{4}$ is a critical point as $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=\frac{1}{4}$.

$f(\frac{1}{4})=4$

So, $4\leq f(x)\leq 11$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using calculus

Comment: Hi @Maverick, I've edited the answer once again (for the last time) with more correct steps and detailed arguement. Please go through it and tell me if everything is clear

Comment: A tag edit isn't worth bumping the question, but if there's occasion to edit could you please delete the complex-geometry tag? (The geometry tag might be appropriate to add, but this isn't complex geometry.)

Comment: So geometry+ complex numbers $\neq$ complex geometry..? O_o @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: @Buraian Yes that's right. Same for analytic-geometry, algebraic-geometry, and others that don't come to mind offhand. <> Hovering over a tag pops up a description in a tooltip. The descriptions generally state explicitly when they should not be used (e.g., "For elementary questions about geometry in the complex plane, use the tags (complex-numbers) and (geometry) instead."), but that's usually at the bottom and isn't always visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Geometric answer for maximum:

[image]

I interpret the expression $|z+3|+ |z^2 -z+4|$ as the "the distance from $-3$ to a point on a circle of radius $2$ (red) plus the length of line segment connecting the point on circle of radius $2$ centered at origin to a point on circle of radius $4$ but with twice the angle centered at (4,0) (blue)". Hopefully that made sense. If it did not, I have kept a Geogebra link at the end.

For the expression $|z+3|+|z^2-z+4|$, we can consider the set of geometric configuration parameterized to it as a function of $\theta$, one can easily check that both $\theta=0$ is a maximum by noticing that the distance function doesn't change to first order in $\theta$ [ the distance function evaluate at $d(\theta+ \Delta \theta)=d(\theta-\Delta \theta)$ for small enough $\Delta \theta$]. Taking higher values of $\Delta \theta$ , we notice the function is decreasing, therefore, $\theta=\pi$ is a maximum.

Here is a picture to specify what I mean:

[image]
The above is when $\theta=\pi$, increasing a bit:

[image]

Decreasing a bit:

[image]

A more detailed way one could convince themself could be through Taylor:

$$ d(\theta  + \Delta \theta) = d(\theta) + \Delta \theta d'(\theta)$$

$$ d(\theta-  \Delta \theta) = d(\theta) - \Delta \theta d'(\theta)$$

Using the fact that $d(\theta-\Delta \theta)= d(\theta+\Delta \theta)$ , we have that $d'(\theta)=0$

### Geometric answer for minimum

We have by triangle inequality ,

$$ |z+3 + z^2 - z+4| \leq |z+3| + |z^2 - z+4|$$

Rewriting:

$$ | z^2 +4 + 3 | \leq |z+3| + |z^2 - z+4|$$

The left most term is the distance from the fixed point three to a varying point on the blue circle. Geometric observation tells us that the least value it can take is $4$ (See FA). Done!

[GeoGebra link](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/bpaqmd8p)

Comment: If you thought this was 'entertaining' , you can check out [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4233318/688539)

Comment: According to first diagram $d_2=|z^2+3|$

Comment: What should $\theta$ be if $d_1+d_2$ were to be minimum .

Comment: Please tell for minimum

Comment: @Buraian $\;d_1+d_2 = 2 \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{13} \gt 8\,$ when $\,z=2i\,$ so the maximum cannot be $\,7\,$.

Comment: Totally redid the answer @dxiv

Comment: @Buraian This [latest](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4420529/17) edit looks a lot better now, however... 1) The claim that the differentials in question are zero is mostly handwaved. 2) Even accepting those claims, what they prove is that the respective points correspond to *local* extrema, but the question is about the *global* maximum and minimum.

Comment: One can easily see that extremum occurs only at  intersection between circle ,x=-2 and x=2. The secondo rder behaviour (seeing distance increases or decreases) as we vary the angle tells us if it is max or min. Now, that we know the set of all max and min and also knowing that the function is bounded, we can identify the globals @dxiv

Answer (score 2):

From the OP's proof by calculus:

> Let $f(x )= \sqrt{13 + 12x} + 2|4x - 1|$ where $x \in [-1, 1].$

The expression $u = \sqrt{13 + 12x}$ is an increasing function of
$x$ in $[-1, 1],$ and $12x = u^2 - 13,$ therefore:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
u + 2 - \tfrac23(u^2 - 13) = 11 - \tfrac13(u - 1)(2u - 1) &
(-1 \leqslant x \leqslant \tfrac14, \ 1 \leqslant u \leqslant 4), \\
u - 2 + \tfrac23(u^2 - 13) = \tfrac13(u + 1)(2u + 1) - 11 &
(\tfrac14 \leqslant x \leqslant 1, \ 4 \leqslant u \leqslant 5).
\end{cases}
$$
No calculus is needed to deduce that $f(x)$
decreases from $11$ to $4$ for $x \in [-1, \tfrac14]$ and
increases from $4$ to $11$ for $x \in [\tfrac14, 1].$

Comment: To get the expression for $f(x),$ we can use:
$$
|z^2 - z + 4| = |z^2 - z + z\bar{z}| = |z|\cdot|z + \bar{z} - 1| =
2|2\Re{z} - 1|.
$$