# What is the connection between optimization and symmetry?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, optimization

I have found that in many optimization problems, there is some sort of "local symmetry" phenomena going on. For example, suppose we have a 'nice' function which has $f'(x)=0$, then we will find that around the points $x_o$ in domain where $f'(x_o)=0$, the function's graph is symmetric about a vertical line passing through $x_o$. Even in higher dimensions, we can see this phenomena, for example, see [this recent question posted and it's commentary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4504529/side-of-largest-possible-cube-inside-a-cone#4504529). Here is [another problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4420529/688539) where I use a similar idea.

Is there some fundamental mathematical truth going on here?

I have learned group theory and that's suppose to quantify our description of symmetry but I can't seem to make a connection of the ideas taught in it and what's going on here?

Comment: I think it would depend on what you mean by 'nice' and 'locally symmetric'. This graph has a relative min at zero, is it 'nice'? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/d7cme41a5b

Comment: There is a sort of local symmetry going on I guess. If you taylor expand it, the quadratic term is leading over leading to symmetry @DavidP

Comment: Asymmetry about a local optimum is quite common in constrained optimization when at least one constraint is active.

Comment: Slightly tangential cautionary remark: Despite what we anticipate from experience, sometimes the extreme points of a function with $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ are *not* on $x=y$.