# Geometry in complex numbers.

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, solution-verification, circles, polygons

> Let $\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3, … , \theta_{10}$ be positive valued angles (in radian) such that $\theta_1+\theta_2+ \theta_3+… + \theta_{10}=2\pi$. Define complex numbers $z_1=e^{i\theta_1}$, $z_k=z_{k-1}e^{i\theta_k}$ for $2\leq k\leq 10$. Then which of these is true? 
> P: $|z_2-z_1|+|z_3-z_2|+…|z_1-z_{10}|\leq 2\pi.$ 
> Q: $|z_2^2-z_1^2|+|z_3^2-z_2^2|+…|z_1^2-z_{10}^2|\leq 4\pi.$

What I understand: $z$ is a unimodular complex number with argument $\theta_1$. The expression $z_k=z_{k-1}e^{i\theta_k}$ just indicates that rotating $z_{k-1}$ anticlockwise by $\theta_{k}$ gives $z_k$. Also, $\theta_1+\theta_2+ \theta_3+… + \theta_{10}=2\pi$ tells us that $z_{10}$ is the complex number $1+0\cdot i$. (X axis rotated on to itself). So I get a figure:

[image]

Now, statement P refers to just the perimeter of the polygon $z_1z_2…z_{10}z_1$, which is less than the circumference of the circle which is $2\pi$.

I have a problem with Q. My solution is to think that the $z_i^2$‘s are just all unimodular complex numbers with all the angles $\theta_i$ doubled. Thus the as we go from $z_1^2$ till $z_{10}^2$, we span the whole unit circle twice, ending at $z_{10}^2=1.$ So the total length of the sides of this (?? Double polygon?) is less than twice the circumference of the circle which is $4\pi$.

I’m a bit uncomfortable with the justification of Q. I think I can prove that the perimeter of a polygon is less than the circumference of its circumcircle (I haven’t attempted it yet)(#). This is a multiple choice question, so no extremely rigorous proofs are required.

Is it okay? How would you make the justification of Q rigorous? I’d also appreciate it if anyone could post an algebraic proof here.

**EDIT**:  I managed to prove (#).
I wrote the perimeter as $$\displaystyle P=2R\sum_{k=1}^{10} \sin\frac{\theta_k}{2}.$$

Now, by Jensen’s inequality, since $\sin x$ is a concave function in $[0,\frac12\pi]$, we have

$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{10}\sum_{k=1}^{10} \sin\frac{\theta_k}{2}\leq \sin\left(\frac{1}{10} \sum_{k=1}^{10} \frac{\theta_k}{2}\right)=\sin \frac{\pi}{10}=\frac{\sqrt 5-1}{4}$$ so that $$\displaystyle P=2R\sum_{k=1}^{10} \sin\frac{\theta_k}{2}\leq 5(\sqrt 5-1)R\lt 2\pi R= Circumference. $$

Comment: This is more precise that your previous question [yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4481438/305862)...

Comment: I know the term "unimodular" seems as a good name for complex numbers of modulus $1$, but that's not the meaning of "unimodular" in Mathematics. The usual name is "unit complex numbers".

Comment: [Here is a related question you may find interesting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4233318/688539)

Comment: YESSS!!!!! Thank you @EthakkaappamwithChai !!!!!! OwO

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai since you post these kinds of answers quite regularly, would you mind taking a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4481438/book-recommendation-for-geometric-intuition? Your kind of answers were the exact thing I was referring to.

Comment: Here is another one that I wrote some time back https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4420356/show-that-4-leq-z3z2-z4-leq-11-where-z-2/4420529#4420529. You can check the profile of user who asked they often ask such type of inequality as you did

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I’m a bit uncomfortable with the justification of Q

For a different hint: $\;|z_2^2-z_1^2| = |z_2+z_1| \cdot |z_2 - z_1| \leq \left(|z_2| + |z_1|\right) \cdot |z_2-z_1| = 2\, |z_2-z_1|\,$.

> the perimeter of a polygon is less than the circumference of its circumcircle

Each side is smaller than the arc subtended, because the shortest distance between two points is the line segment between them.

Comment: Nice! Thanks and +1

Comment: Hello sir/ma’am @dxiv could you please see my edit and help me to prove $5(\sqrt 5-1)\lt 2\pi $? Like, from the approximate values it’s obvious, but still…

Comment: @insipidintegrator More generally, you get $\,P \le 2R \,n \sin \frac{\pi}{n}\,$ from Jensen's inequality, then see [Proving $n\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})<\pi<n\tan(\frac{\pi}{n})$ ; obtaining results from it.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533502/proving-n-sin-frac-pin-pin-tan-frac-pin-obtaining-results-from/).

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved.